# Parceljs doesn't completely strip comments

Tags: comments, bundling-and-minification, uglifyjs, parceljs

We are using Parceljs v2 for bundling our SPAs.

We've been noticed by our customer's security team that the comments are not completely stripped from the bundles:
[image]

We use the default settings for Parcel. In the docs is specified that uglify.js is used by default and seems it doesn't do its job.

Comment: Instead of upvoting maybe you should provide some explanations. What's wrong with my question ?

Answer (score 0):

For Parcel v2 using SWC here's the solution I found removed all comments

In the root of your project, make file `.terserrc`:

```
{
  "mangle": true,
  "compress": true,
  "format": {
    "comments": false
  }
}
```

for more details, check [the docs](https://parceljs.org/languages/javascript/#minification). I find that with Parcel, reading the small print from their official channels is the way to troubleshooting. Aside from that, this bundler truly is magic.